Finding the shape of the surface of water within a spinning bucket with a leakage at the bottom of the wall
Finding the shape of the surface of water within a spinning bucket with a leakage at the bottom of the wall
Let think in the classic example of a bucket half full with water that start spinning at a constant angular speed, which have a well known solution of a parabolic shape in the surface of water, as explained here.
Now, I want to modify the bucket for a rectangular slide like the implemented in the following Youtube video (pretty good video, I recommend you to watch it - is not mine by the way).
Now, the real modification I want to study is making a hole in one wall at the bottom of this bucket/slide, and see how the shape will change as the bucket start to empty: my intuition tell the problem will have two stages:
Hypothesis:

At first, the level will fall at first evenly keeping the parabolic shape unchanged, as subtracting a constant value of a quadratic equation.
But at some time, the level of water wouldn't be enough to cover the full bucket/slide detaching in two sections, and the section that would have the hole will continue to empty lowering the level, but the parabolic shape will change shifting its parameters respecting the parabolic shape of the section that would be fixed now since water don't have how to escape.


I hope you could help me to model and answer this problem in detail, in a way to verify if my hypothesis a mistaken or not.
I have tried to do what is done in the video, but since now the average level of the water changes with time: now for determine the volume of water within the bucket/slide the height and the base are variables, I have not been able to relate them so far.
I am not convinced that after the level split in two its still required to assume the shape is a parabola, but instead, the shape should arise from the dynamics: I have studied so far two parabolas scenarios: (i) that at the bottom the water rises continuously meaning the parabola vertex is located where it start to dried, and (ii) that the parabola shape is kept unchanged and only the average level moves, which implies at the section it start to dry there is a sharp edge. Both makes sense to me, and both are different, so I hope you could deliver a solution of $\text{Stage}\,2$ without an preconceived assumption about the shape.
Here is a Desmos with my two attempts/assumptions tested: from the Free Body Diagram looks more accurate the second attempt (blue), but from the gif animation I felt more realistic the other one (orange).


Update 1
I have uploaded what I did but using a strong assumption: that after the level of water get split in two, the farthest point with water from the hole at the bottom of the wall is located at the vertex of the parabola.
I think this result, even if its right, it is a mistaken way to solve it: from the kinematics I should have to been able of finding the shape without assumptions, but I have been unable to model $\text{Stage}\,2$ finding some relation among the base and the height of the parabola.
I tried to consider the rotational speed, but over the hole since water cannot be moving outside due the wall the rotational speed effect looks it cancel out, but it don't fully convince me since the speed in the opposite vertex of the parabola is having a Normal fully cancelled with the weight, so the only component on the horizontal axis is the centrifugal force, and it should (I believe), be pushing water out of the hole.
I am very lost, I hope you could help me. Thanks beforehand.



Update 2
I have studied also the assumption recommended by @mmesser314: the parabola never change its form $$h(x)=\frac{w^2x^2}{2g}+h_0(t)$$ and found the following:




The answer and video you linked start reasoning from forces. You might try that instead of starting from an equation you suspect is the one to use. You might also ask yourself if the graph flattening out to a line shows the expected surface. If you add or remove water to a bucket would you expect the forces at the surface to change? Would you expect the shape to change?

@mmesser314 I think that when the level of water achieve the bottom the equilibrium will change: if I just displace the parabola down the bottom, when achieving the empty stage the slope would be huge in the little section of water I will have which don't look right for me, instead, I think it would be more feasible to consider that the bucket is shrinking with the section of bucket is still with water, which I believe would be equivalent to a parabolic behavior that is changing in shape.

@mmesser314 as example how I got stuck: if I think in the classic Torircelli's approach, now I have the extra pressure due centrifugal force plus now the Volume is not just a variable of the height but also of the base $V=ph(t)b(t)$ with $p$ the depth of the bucket/slice... and if I try to use the formula of the video I will be making the assumption of a parabolic shape, and maybe it is not the case now... so I am stuck defining the problem from the very beginning

@mmesser314 I added my attempt but as you will see I am very lost. Hope you could elaborate in an answer.

This problem should be very much like the problem where the floor is below the bottom of the parabola. The only difference should be how you integrate the volume of water. In the original problem, there is a hole in the middle and a raised edge. The volume of water that was below the original surface in the hole is the same as the volume of water that is now above the original surface around the edge. For your problem, the volume above the floor around the edge is the total volume of the water.

@mmesser314 .... but thus also means I am still assuming the parabola shape of the water surface: shouldn't it would change since now the mass is variable? I'm thinking in something like the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation, I mean, even when there is no angular acceleration involved, the centrifugal force and the leakage should interact somehow, that is what my intuition says, maybe mistakenly, but anyway, I should been able to found the new equilibrium without assuming the system will kept its parabolic shape as assumption

@mmesser314 The assumption you tell, will imply that before getting empty the water would have a huge surface slope: Does have sense to you?

The video you linked tells you how to solve the problem. You don't assume a parabola. You derive it. You don't assume the rocket equation. You look at the forces. The video shows that the surface is a parabola even when the parabola goes below the floor. The video tells you how to calculate c when the entire parabola is above the floor. You will need to do it differently as I described for your case.

@mmesser314 I was uploading an attempt made under your assumption... I hope you could also see it.

"The assumption you tell, will imply that before getting empty the water would have a huge surface slope. Does have sense to you? " The slope does not change or get steeper as the parabola drops, even when it goes below the floor. Your orange Desmos curve in the animation is not correct. I fully agree with @mmesser314 comments. The surface curve is fully determined by the centrifugal force already.

I deleted my answer because I found I had made an error in determining the integral that is not easily fixed.

The solution for R where the parabolic curve intersects the base of the vessel is pretty horrific https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+1%2F2+k+%28d+-+2+R%29+%2B+%28%28d%5E3+-+8+R%5E3%29+w%5E2%29%2F%2848+b%29+%3DA%2F2+for+R

@KDP From the link in Wolfram-Alpha, there are 4 formulations which 3 are horryble but the last one is simple: maybe try to see if the difficult ones makes non-sense from the physical point of view (I don't know, maybe have some complex value hidden within if you asume the constants are all non-negative)... at least in both my attempts I never saw some term related to the 3rd square root of something.

@Joako If you look carefully, that last simple solution has condition, $k \ne 0$ and $b/ne 0$ and $\omega = 0 $ which is not very helpful because it is only valid when the container is not rotating!

@Joako As soon as you integrate $k+\omega^2 x^2/(2g) dx$
to find the cross sectional area under the curve, you end up with a polynomial of degree 3 in x and then things get very complicated. They even get $x^3$
in the video. k is the vertical offset of the curve.

Joako, I would strongly suggest building this setup and videoing what happens.  It can easily be done with craft store or hardware store materials.  Pages of math and simulations will not mean much if they don't correspond to reality, and with the demo you may get a result you were not expecting.

As far as h(t) is concerned the height will drop more or linearly until the lowest point of the parabola reaches the base and then h(t) will increase dramatically. I have tried to solve for h as a function of cross sectional area but the result is complicated. If you are trying to make a computer simulation it might be best to use numerical techniques to find the small change in h when there is small change in water volume. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+1%2F48+%2824+d+h+-+64+sqrt%282%29+h+sqrt%28%28g+h%29%2Fw%5E2%29+%2B+%28d%5E3+w%5E2%29%2Fg%29+%3D+A%2F2+for+h

Here is small Geogebra construction https://www.geogebra.org/classic/aaqhgpum you can play with. You can see that when h is initially 3.7m there is $28 \ m^3$ in the container and $14 \ m^3 $ of water is removed from the container by the time h=0. The level has to drop another 10m to remove the last $14 \  m^3$ so the level has to drop much faster to remove water at a similar rate.

@KDP Is an interesting model, I am not familiarized with GeoAlgebra but it was similar with what I did in Desmos, maybe my intuition is mistaken, but let move to an extreme example: think the bucket slide is closed on top and make $w$ fast enough that all the liquid is almost parallel to the walls (so a quadratic with a huge slope, and $h_0$ well below the bottom of the bucket), its weird to me to imagine getting empty with such as slope, but is like a centrifuge works at the end. I am trying to figure out the PDE/ODE at last... maybe the 2nd attempt results aren't bad at the end.
